# erlang mixing sync and async functions

Tags: asynchronous, erlang, erlang-otp

Is it possible to block a synchronous function (handle_call) to wait for a asynchronous call (handle_cast) in a different module?

i.e.
How can I make the synchronous function wait (i.e. block) until a specific "done" message from a asynchronous function is received? (and only then continue with execution)
Both modules are following gen_server and gen_fsm behaviors.

Can handle_info be used in some way?

Regards
/Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to save away the reference to the sender in `handle_call`, and call `gen_server:reply` at a later point.  That is, while you'd normally write your `handle_call` function like this:

```
handle_call(foo, _From, State) ->
    {reply, {ok, bar}, State}.
```

you'd do something like this:

```
handle_call(foo, From, State = #state{pending = Pending}) ->
    NewState = State#state{pending = [From | Pending]},
    {noreply, NewState}.
```

And then later, perhaps in `handle_info`:

```
handle_info({bar_event, Data}, State = #state{pending = [Head | Tail]) ->
    gen_server:reply(Head, {ok, Data}),
    NewState = State#state{pending = Tail},
    {noreply, NewState}.
```

That means that when a process calls `gen_server:call(Pid, foo)`, it will block until the server process receives `{bar_event, Data}`, at which point the server will return the data contained in the event to the caller.

I tried to keep the example simple by storing information about the callers in a "stack", so in the case of multiple concurrent callers the last caller will return first and vice versa.  In many cases you'll want to save caller info with a key of some kind, that you can look up when you get the asynchronous event.

This can also be done in a gen_fsm process; the function calls and return values are similar.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly what I needed. I've completely forgotten about the {noreply, ... }"return".

Comment: Be careful doing this as the `gen_server:call` has a built-in timeout of 5 sec after which an error is automatically generated. The length of timeout can be set with a 3rd argument, either millisecs or `infinity`.

Comment: Yup, I ran into that issue in a previous application. Now I usually have either infinity set or I pass a timeout value (that is intended for the callback.) This does make things a bit "messy" though :(